# including RTF inserted images to be sent in an email as HTML

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code to insert images into an RTF box:

```
Public Sub InsertPicture()
        'Use the code 'InsertPicture()' to show the dialog and insert a picture
        Try
            Dim GetPicture As New OpenFileDialog
            GetPicture.Filter = "PNGs (*.png), Bitmaps (*.bmp), GIFs (*.gif), JPEGs (*.jpg)|*.bmp;*.gif;*.jpg;*.png|PNGs (*.png)|*.png|Bitmaps (*.bmp)|*.bmp|GIFs (*.gif)|*.gif|JPEGs (*.jpg)|*.jpg"
            GetPicture.FilterIndex = 1
            GetPicture.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
            If GetPicture.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim SelectedPicture As String = GetPicture.FileName
                Dim Picture As Bitmap = New Bitmap(SelectedPicture)
                Dim cboard As Object = Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text)
                Clipboard.SetImage(Picture)
                Dim PictureFormat As DataFormats.Format = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap)
                If RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.CanPaste(PictureFormat) Then
                    RichTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Paste(PictureFormat)
                End If
                Clipboard.Clear()
                Clipboard.SetText(cboard)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

It works okay and inserts/shows the image fine, however the images are not showing when converting the RTF to HTML and sending as a HTML email.

im guessing its because its not inserting the images as attachments, how can i do this for each image inserted into the RTF box?

Comment: You wont get images into HTML that way I can assure you that. You can either attach them as attachments and reference them or embed them into the html. Option 1 some clients wont show the image due to security unless user wants to see them and option 2 is more advanced and requires creating a view ... its your choice...

Comment: how would i be able to insert them into the rtf box and then attach as email attachments, or when submitting to send the email, loop through any images in the rtf box and attach each one in the loop?

Comment: you would need to keep image paths in a collection of sort for adding as attachments  as you need the paths to the images themselves.